# Javascript: challenge - not getting the right answer

Tags: javascript, loops, palindrome

I'm redoing the Project Euler challenges in Javascript. The task is to get the largest palindrome number (https://projecteuler.net/problem=4). Now I get the following code:

```js
var lpp = 0;
  for (var a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < 1000; b++) {
      var str = (a*b).toString();
      if (str.charAt(0) === str.charAt(5)) {
        if (str.charAt(1) === str.charAt(4)) {
          if (str.charAt(2) === str.charAt(3)) {
            lpp = str;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(lpp);
```

The output of the code is 580085, which I know is the wrong answer as I had previously done the challenges in Python.

Comment: Please elaborate why I was downvoted for this? I've done my homework, put the effort in the code, the question is rather specific. What's wrong with it?

Comment: you "assume" the a*b will always be going up - if your logic was the same in python, your python result would also be wrong

Comment: You're starting `a` and `b` as 1-digit numbers. Shouldn't you be doing something like `var a = 100` and `var b = 100` so that you begin with 3-digit numbers?

Comment: ... but they are, aren't they?

Comment: Eh? `0` is a 1-digit number. You could also start at `999` and work your way down.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin - you're right. This however, would not change the answer.

Comment: a*b will not always go up ... once b hits 999 and a is 1, result = 999, next loop a is 2, b is 0 ... 0 < 999

Comment: *"The question is rather specific."* No it's not. In fact, there's not a single question mark in your entire post.

Comment: I would personally start `a` at 100, and start `b` at `a` - but that's just to do things quickly

Comment: `lpp = Math.max(lpp, a*b);` is the answer to your question

Comment: Thanks guys - I did not think about the points you've raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem with your code is that it just stores the **last** palindrome it finds, which is not necessarily the largest. If we tweak the code a tad and add a check that the current evaluated product is indeed larger than the previously found palindrome, you'll get the correct answer (906609):

```js
var lpp = 0;
  for (var a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < 1000; b++) {
      var tmp = a*b;
      if (tmp < lpp) {
          continue;
      }
      var str = tmp.toString();
      if (str.charAt(0) === str.charAt(5)) {
        if (str.charAt(1) === str.charAt(4)) {
          if (str.charAt(2) === str.charAt(3)) {
            lpp = tmp;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(lpp);
```

Comment: The product result string will not always be 6 digits long. Thus charAt(5) will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You just don't check if the newly found palindrome is **higher than the last one** found.

Also, iterate only 3 digit numbers and use `str.split("").reverse().join("")` for string reversion.

```js
var lpp = 0
for (var a = 100; a < 1000; a++) 
    for (var b = 100; b < 1000; b++) 
    {
        var mult = a * b
        var str = (mult).toString()
        if (str == str.split("").reverse().join("") && mult > lpp)
             lpp = mult
    }
console.log(lpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var lpp = 0;
for (var a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < 1000; b++) {
        var str = (a * b).toString();
        var j = str.length - 1;
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length ; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
            j--;
        }
        if (count == 0)
            lpp = str;
    }
}
console.log(lpp);
```